# Another proof the $\operatorname{rank} (AB) \leq \operatorname{rank} (A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given a matrix $A$, if the rank of $A$ is defined to be the highest order of non-vanishing minor of $A$.

If we apply the above definition, how to check that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A)$?

Comment: The columns of $AB$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$...

Comment: I mean using the above definition to prove. In other words, how to prove  the highest order of non-vanishing minor of AB is less than that of A?

Comment: The minors of $AB$ are a linear combination of minors of $A$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula)

Comment: You can use functoriality of exterior powers, which consist of minors: $$\textstyle\bigwedge^k(AB)=\bigwedge^kA\,\bigwedge^kB$$ This is equivalent to a general form of Cauchy-Binet.

Comment: It completely baffles me that someone studying abstract von Neumann algebra has trouble with basic linear algebra.